# How to copy an array of object and change only objects indexes using Ramda?

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

I am receiving an array like this: Steps: `[{ One: 1, Two: 2, }, {One: 3, Two: 4, }]`

and I want to copy this array `Steps` only changing the indexes to lowercase, like `one` and `two`, copying the values..

How I can do this using ramda?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This generic `mapKeys` functions accepts another function to transform the keys (**R.toLower** in this case). The function converts the object to entries with **R.toPairs**, evolves the 1st item of each entry (the key) using the supplied function (`cb`), and then converts the entries back to object using **R.fromPairs**.

```js
const { pipe, toPairs, map, evolve, fromPairs, toLower } = R

const mapKeys = cb => pipe(
  toPairs,
  map(evolve([cb])),
  fromPairs,
)

const steps =  [{ One: 1, Two: 2, }, { One: 3, Two: 4 }]

const result = map(mapKeys(toLower))(steps) // call mapKeys on an array of objects

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's a fascinating use of `evolve`!  I don't know that I've ever passed an array to it, but it makes sense.

Comment: I think Ramda should consider adding a function somewhat equivalent to `(fn) => pipe (toPairs, map(fn), fromPairs)`.  This seems such a common pattern.

Comment: Happy to surprise you. Since the addition of fromEntries to JS this pattern replaced for...in and entries.refuce. Having a general purpose object map would be nice.

Comment: Awesome man! but I have one question ... why I need to use [ ] inside evolve?

Comment: R.evolve accepts am object of transformations. For each property in the object (if it exists in the original object) a transformation is applied. In this case the object is an array, and I want to transform the 1st element to lower case. I can use an array or use an object `{ 0: toLowerCase }`.